# Impossible clean PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I want clean the PictureBox image, so I make this code:  `TransparentPictureBox.Image = Nothing`, the image don't disappear and I obtain all new image overlapping to the previous. How can I fix this?

[image: initial image]

[image: overlapping]

I stay using a custom control, this is the class:

```
Public Class TransparentPictureBox
Inherits PictureBox

Public Sub New()
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True)
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, False)
End Sub

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20  ' Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: if the PB doesnt also have an image assigned to BackgroundImage, you may not showing all the relevant code.

Comment: The PictureBox.Image = Nothing works for me.  As Plutonix stated, update the post with the additional code you're using to clear/load the image, I suspect something else is causing this issue.

Comment: I'm using a custom control. I've pasted the class of the control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The control is working exactly as you designed it.**

With the [ControlStyles.Opaque](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option set to `True`, it does not draw its background:

> If true, the control is drawn opaque and the background is not painted.

When you set the `Image` property to `Nothing`, you're expecting it to be emptied.
How does a `PictureBox` draw itself though? It first draws the **background** color, then it draws the image on top of that. Since you've disabled background painting, though, the background doesn't get drawn and the previous image doesn't get erased.

Why do you have that option set? Remove it if that is not the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Because I want a trasparent PictureBox control, this PictureBox is situated on another PictureBox with the green field. If I remove Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True) I obtain the PictureBox with the shield with a quadratic blank.

Comment: I'll give it to you straight: WinForms transparency support sucks.  End of story.  Move to WPF if you want that kind of flexibility.  One option is to draw a composite image at run-time with the transparency you want and put that into a single PictureBox.

Answer (score -1):

Just write this although this not optimal solution but it will work
    picturebox1.imagelocation = ""

Comment: You might try this    PictureBox1.CreateGraphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)

Comment: The only problem is that a white background appears behind the image.

Comment: well instead of using' me.backcolor' you can use any color you want like color.black, color.wheat or same as the background colour you are using

Comment: if I use color.trasparent appear a black background and not the green field of the image that I've uploaded

Comment: PictureBox1.Height = 0